# When a cocoa method wants a selector as a parameter, how do I express this in ruby?

Tags: cocoa, selector, macruby

In [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingAlertSheets.html) tutorial for sheet programming in cocoa, I am told to invoke the following method:

```
[[alert beginSheetModalForWindow:[searchField window] 
    modalDelegate:self 
    didEndSelector:@selector(alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:) 
    contextInfo:nil];
```

I have written this as follows in ruby,

```
alert.beginSheetModalForWindow(self.window, 
    modalDelegate:self,
    didEndSelector: :alertDidEnd,
    contextInfo:nil)
```

Of course, the `didEndSelector` part is wrong. Later in my code I have a method alertDidEnd, which takes returnCode and contextInfo as arguments. When I looked at `self.methods` I noticed that the method is listed as `alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:`. In the sample code above an '@' is used to mark the selector. This is accomplished in Macruby with a symbol, but in this case the symbol would contain colons, which is not allowed. How should I represent this method name as a symbol? I wasn't able to find this information on my own, where should I have looked that I didn't?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the [MacRuby docs](http://www.macruby.org/trac/wiki/MacRubyTutorial), symbols are bridged with selectors. So you'd do:

```
alert.beginSheetModalForWindow(self.window, 
    modalDelegate:self,
    didEndSelector: :'alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:',
    contextInfo:nil)
```

Comment: Hmm... still doesn't call the method though. Does the symbol need to include the entire footprint? When I puts self.methods.sort I noticed that the alertDidEnd method is actually called alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo: . That has a bunch of colons in it: can I still include this as a symbol?

Comment: @Ziggy: Yes, it needs the entire selector. I didn't notice the selector itself was different in the two snippets. I've fixed the answer now.

Comment: This seems to be the right syntax, but the method isn't being called. You have answered my question, but it seems there is something else broken somewhere. Back to work!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a Symbol? It seems to work in RubyCocoa.